# Newtonsoft.JSON appends Lists when deserializing with FromObject

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, constructor, json.net

I've simplified my problem down to this bit of sample code using `Newtonsoft.JSON.Linq` and `JObject.ToObject<T>()`

The issue here is that in the constructor of `Test` a default value is added to the list `Nums`. However if I serialize and then deserialize the object, Newtonsoft is not replacing the list, but appending to the values set by the constructor.

I cannot change the deserialization process, as that is in a core library.

How can I set a default value for my list without duplication? Thanks.

```
class Test
{
    public List<int> Nums { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public Test()
    {
        // add default value
        this.Nums.Add(0);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test job = new Test(); // job.Nums.Count == 1

        JObject jJob = JObject.FromObject(job);

        job = jJob.ToObject<Test>(); // job.Nums.Count == 2
    }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mbR4R9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create ctor overload which takes default value.

```
class Test
{
    public List<int> Nums { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        this.Nums = new List<int>();
    }

    public Test(int def) : this()
    {
        this.Nums.Add(def);
    }
}
```

Here is usage:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test job = new Test(0); 
        Console.WriteLine(job.Nums.Count);

        JObject jJob = JObject.FromObject(job);

        job = jJob.ToObject<Test>();
        Console.WriteLine(job.Nums.Count); // This is 1 again.
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising

Comment: `public Test(bool init = true)` works as Newtonsoft will call the constructor with the default value of bool `default(bool)` which is false ignoring the auto argument, which code will honor. Then you can have an if statement.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell it how to deserialize the object

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer { 
                        ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace 
                };
job = jJob.ToObject<Test>(serializer);
```

Properly gives you 1 item after deserializing.

Comment: From OP `I cannot change the deserialization process, as that is in a core library.`